# Showing that a function is continuous using its Taylor series

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, taylor-expansion

I'm not sure if the technique I'm applying is correct. I've been asked to show that $e^x$ and $sin(x)$ are continuous functions, and I'm stuck on doing it the conventional way. However, I know and can show that all polynomials are continuous, and I know that both $e^x$ and $sin(x)$ can be expressed as infinite polynomials. Would that be enough to imply that these functions are therefore continuous, or does the argument break down due to the polynomial not being finite?

Comment: If a function is given by power series convergent in some open set $O$, then the function is continuous (in fact smooth) in $O$. So yes your reasoning is basically correct.

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122 No! What you say about power series is right, but not because of properties of *polynomials*. There is no such thing as "infinite polynomials" -- and properties of power series (or analytic functions) are not trivial corollaries of properties of polynomials.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Only polynomials of finite degree
are guaranteed to be continuous.

For example,
consider
$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^n
= \dfrac1{1-x}
$.
This is not continuous at
$x=1$.

For your cases,
you need to show  that
$|e^x-e^y|$ and
$|\sin(x)-\sin(y)|$
go to zero as
$|x-y| \to 0$.

Try looking at identities
regarding
$e^x$ and $\sin(x)$.

Comment: $g(x) = \sum_{n \geq 0} x^n$ converges for $x \in (-1, 1)$ and $g$ is indeed continuous in this interval.

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122 Yes, but not by the argument "polynomials are continuous." The OP is equating polynomials (finite degree) and power series (infinite series), which is not a good idea and won't lead to a correct argument.

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122: A polynomial $p(x)$ of finite degree converges for *all* finite$x$. The example I gave does not converge for $|x| > 1$.